# AS2 Flash - Quiz IF Statements Not Working

Tags: flash, if-statement, actionscript-2

I have an if statement that does not seem to work for my quiz, it's in AS2.

```
var check_answer_num:Number = (answer_num+1);

var tmp_answer:String = xml_engine.firstChild.childNodes[quiz_current].childNodes[1].firstChild;
var tmp_user_answer:String = xml_engine.firstChild.childNodes[quiz_current].childNodes[check_answer_num].firstChild;

if(tmp_answer==tmp_user_answer) {
    trace("YES");
} else {
    trace("NO");
}
```

When I test the quiz it outputs NO for every answer even if it is correct. Not sure if it's a defining vars problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post some sample XML?

Comment: Hi there,XML:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Quiz>
 <Question>
  <QText>Who is the main character?</QText>
  <QAns>Brad Smith</QAns>
  <Option>Al Ahkmed Zahid</Option>
  <Option>Brad Smith</Option>
  <Option>Dinah Soares</Option>
  <Option>Jack Knoff</Option>
 </Question>
 
 <Question>
  <QText>What was Brad Smith originally?</QText>
  <QAns>A Homeless Guy</QAns>
  <Option>A Homeless Guy</Option>
  <Option>A Church Minister</Option>
  <Option>A Homeless Guy</Option>
  <Option>A Hippy</Option>
 </Question>

</Quiz>

Comment: trace your variables please and give the output for trace(tmp_answer); trace(tmp_user_answer);

Comment: Thanks...NO
Brad Smith
Brad Smith
NO
A Homeless Guy
A Homeless Guy
NO
Al Ahkbar Saheed
Al Ahkbar Saheedr
0 0

Comment: Hmm okay that's very strange a string comparison of those two value should yield true, the only other thing I can think of here is that for some reason one of the two Strings has some extra whitespace for some reason, can you try if(StringUtil.trim(tmp_answer)==StringUtil.trim(tmp_user_answer)), ah I see this is AS2 as well I'm not so sure about string comparison in AS2 versus AS3 which is what I'm used to.  You may need to use a .equals method on one string, I'll see if I can dig up the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think your XML traversal may be amiss based on the sample XML that you gave.

Here's your XML (just for clarity):

```
<Quiz> 
 <Question> 
   <QText>Who is the main character?</QText> 
   <QAns>Brad Smith</QAns> 
   <Option>Al Ahkmed Zahid</Option> 
   <Option>Brad Smith</Option> 
   <Option>Dinah Soares</Option> 
   <Option>Jack Knoff</Option> 
 </Question> 
 <Question> 
   <QText>What was Brad Smith originally?</QText> 
   <QAns>A Homeless Guy</QAns> 
   <Option>A Homeless Guy</Option> 
   <Option>A Church Minister</Option> 
   <Option>A Homeless Guy</Option> 
   <Option>A Hippy</Option> 
 </Question> 
</Quiz>
```

Now, here's your declaration of `tmp_answer`:

```
var tmp_answer:String = xml_engine.firstChild.childNodes[quiz_current].childNodes[1].firstChild;
```

Assuming that `xml_engine` is the entire doc represented above, `xml_engine.firstChild` is the first `<Question>` node, which I don't think is what you want.

Try this:

```
var tmp_answer:String = xml_engine.childNodes[quiz_current].childNodes[1].firstChild
```

That should give you "Brad Smith" for the first question

Comment: Hey, that gives me the actual XML value inside it's tags like <QAns>Brad Smith</QAns> rather than plain 'Brad Smith'. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `.nodeValue` to each of your expressions (e.g.: `xml_engine.childNodes[quiz_current].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue`)